altenating direction implicit method
as in my previous question comparaison between numerical speed and theoretical speed , i'm studying the articlehttps://downloads.hindawi.com/journals/jmath/2023/5527728.pdf?_ga=2.50574505.1411133042.1716925673-1275339179.1715808341 ,i'm not sure that i understand correctlky the method that the authors use ,what i understood is this :
$u(x,(n+1)\Delta t)=u^{n+1}$  , so  the solution is $u_3$?

in addition first in this algorithm we need to write first
$un=u_0;$ where $u0$ is the itial condtion and nt is  number of time step  and dt is time step size
% Loop over time steps
for n = 1:nt
$ un = u^*;$
$ t = t + dt;$
Then, we perform a loop over the $y$-direction:
for $j=1: N_y$
for $i=1: N_x$
set $\alpha_i, \beta_i, \gamma_i$, and $f_{i j}^n$ by equations (Algorithm 1)
end
and the we Solve  using the Thomas algorithm
end
also  the author says :
calculate $u_{ij}^{* * * } $ using the piecewise linear interpolation but what i understand is that the interpolation give $u^{* * * } =u_2$ and not $u^{n+1}$ as in the picture 
and to solve equation $7$ we have :
$$\frac{u_{i j}^{* * * * } - u_2{i j}((n-1)\Delta t)}{\frac{\Delta t}{2}}=L_{ADI}^x u_{i j}^{* * * * } $$
$$\frac{- u_{i j}^{* * * * } +u_{i j}3}{\frac{\Delta t}{2}}=L{ADI}^y u_{i j}^3$
is thats right ? may be i'm lost with symbols


what is your "previous question"? 2. you may have to fix the symbols, it is a little difficult to track.


Can you restate you problem and isolate features of broader interest. to our community. It seems that the way to help you is to read and digest the paper in question. This is best done in person.
